# Using Get-WMIobject Process to locate the path of a service and pull the version information

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, get-wmiobject

I need to verify the version of a service running on our systems. So I have got close but cannot seem to figure it out. I am using a `Get-WmiObject` process looking for the process of the service that is running. Then pull back the path of that executable that is "the" service. Then retrieve the `FileVersion` of said executable file.

```
foreach ($Computer in $Computers ) {
    $zabbix = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer -Filter "name like '%zabbix%'" |
              Select -ExpandProperty Path |
              Get-ItemProperty |
              Select-Object -Property VersionInfo |
              ? {$_.ProductVersion}
}
Write-Host "$zabbix - $Computer"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `?`/ `Where-Object` because you aren't filtering.

```
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers ){
    $zabbix = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
        (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name like '%zabbix%'" |
        Select -ExpandProperty Path | Get-ItemProperty).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
    }
    Write-Host "$zabbix - $Computer"
}
```

Comment: That kind of worked but it seems like it is pulling the local host path rather than the remote system. To test it, I set the $computer variable and run the (Get-WmiObject all the was to .ProductVersion and I get an error.

    `code`Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\zabbix_agentd.exe' because it does not exist.
At line:2 char:42
+            Select -ExpandProperty Path | Get-ItemProperty).VersionInfo.ProductVe ...`code`

I logged on that machine and the service is present and running.

Comment: You can wrap it in an `Invoke-Command` so that the querying of `VersionInfo` is done on the remote computer. I've edited my answer to do that.